# How to print webpage without URL littering

Tags: printing, webpage

I am trying to wipe out a dying hybrid drive using DBAN.  I am following [this webpage](https://www.alphr.com/how-to-use-dban).  The drive is in an external enclosure and will be connected to the port of an old Windows 7 machine.  I do not want to connect the machine to the internet, so I want to print the above webpage to PDF.  I tried using both Firefox, Edge, and Chrome.  The printer driver I was using was PhantomPDF's PDF writer.  However, on Firefox, I also tried Firefox's "Save to PDF" and "Microsoft Print to PDF".  In all cases, the preview shows the printout is littered with URLs which are not visible on the webpage itself.

Is there a more fundamental system setting which is causing the PDF printout to go wonkily so across browsers and printer drivers?

P.S. Based on suggested answers, I found [this site](https://www.printfriendly.com), which achieves a good printout.  However, I would still like to know what is causing the URL littering, and whether it can be banished without resorting to a 3rd party service.

---

**Attempts made to solve the problem**
I tried *gronostaj*'s disablement of `::after` links, which got rid of most of the clutter.  There is still residual clutter.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## That particular website is designed to do that.

Here's Firefox's inspector with print simulation enabled (circled red on the screenshot):

[image: Screenshot of website, with ::after pseudoelement containing the URL highlighted]

The inspector is accessed by right-clicking any link and selecting *Inspect*. Then you can expand the link node `<a href="https://…">` and click on `::after`. That will highlight just the URL part.

Under the print simulation button you can see the CSS property that creates `::after` pseudoelements on all links with their URLs. Hovering mouse pointer over that property will reveal a checkbox. Uncheck it to hide link URLs.

Comment: @gronostag: Thanks.  I tried this, and it got rid of most of the clutter, but there was still some residue.  I included an image in the originally posted question.

Comment: @user2153235 That's their menu I think? Try deleting these elements altogether in inspector's tree.

Comment: I think you answered my question.  There *is* a way to print the web page minus the clutter, but you have to finagle switches that may be unfamiliar to non-web-designers.  Thanks.

Comment: @user2153235 Exactly. It's a problem with this particular website though, rather than with browsers or web in general. You have to fix stuff that their designers messed up (or incorrectly assumed would be better for you).

Comment: That's almost funny, that someone would think this is what people want.  That's probably not the explanation so much as someone having committed a design oversight somewhere.  In my days, I wrote my own HTML, but these days, tools do that.  Maybe it's a default of the tool.